Unity XR simulated environment with tracked images
I am working on a project for university with a team of other developers. In this assignment we are making a AR presentation of the Pokemon trading card game. The main goal of this is to have the Pokemon models to appear above the cards as they appear in real life. This will make it seem like there are actually 2 Pokemon fighting each other.
We are using Unity 22.3.12 for this project and I am responsible for the AR tracking. As none of us have access to a headset at home, I have opted to test with the simulated testing environment available with the XR packages. The simulated environment I am using here consists of 2 grey quads making a floor and wall as well as a plane with a texture of the Hitmonchan Pokemon card.
I have managed to get the image to become detected and spawn a prefab however, the spawned prefab seems to move independently. There is only a single camera in the scene and I have not set up any custom camera controller. It seems like the prefab exists in an environment that is navigated differently, causing the tracking to desync.

My goal is to make it so the cameras don't move independently. I've watched quite a few tutorials on getting this set up but none of them have  worked.  I am using MRTK3  which may be interfering but I am not sure.
I am very new to AR in Unity and have been struggling with this for a while. Maybe I have some incorrect settings somewhere or forgot to click a button. I'm unsure how to move from this.
Thanks

What is it you actually want to do though? Please edit your question to make this clear.

@Spaghetti done

I'm getting dizzy due to that image...

My question is what do you mean by "Cameras"? Are you using multiple Camera gameobjects in Unity and for what reason? e.g. theoretically you need only one camera which emulates the AR device's camera in movement and orientation. Do you want your cards and pokemon to be moving as well so they are always in view? Do you want to keep them in certain position in space and only see them if you move your device towards the point in physical space that would match their virtual position? You need to explain a bit more.

@NPatch updated for clarity

I'm still not understanding why you say there's only one Camera in the scene, yet in the last paragraph you are trying to "make it so the cameras don't move independently".  Just to be clear, the first rotation I see in the gif, looks like you are rotating the Scene View camera which is not a camera that's there in the build. So I'm guessing your 3d model is parented to the Camera gameobject in the scene and you want it to be static like the Card. Sounds like you just want to parent the pokemon itself to the card so that it stays in place or just don't parent it to the camera.

@NPatch The card exists within a simulated environment, not the scene. It should be treated as if it is read from an XR headset like the Metaquest. After the card is seen inside this environment, the Pokemon model should be tracked to it.  I am moving the game camera around not the scene camera. The model is not parented to the camera it exists alone in the scene

Are you using a Simulated Tracked Image for that card and spawning the model through an AR Tracked Image Manager on the origin?

@NPatch Yes I am

I tried the AR mobile template, dead simple setup. Changed the unity logo to a pokemon card texture quad and created the RefImage Library. Added the AR TRacked Image Manager to the scene with the ref image library and set up a sphere prefab to be spawned on recognition. It spawned fixed on the card in world space. Then I played a bit with the origin and added a rotation to the XROrigin obj to see the object spawning, bc at first it's already in view. But I noticed that that rotation is not taken into account for Simulated Camera, so navigation desynced them.

I notice that you have XR Device Simulator on for some reason. I removed earlier comments...just take it out and it should be fine. It tries to control your scene, all the while AR Simulation is turned on, which also provides its own navigation. Two competing navigation drivers for the same car.
